# How to make zsh forward-word behaviour same as in bash/emacs

Tags: zsh, zshrc

zsh forward-word acts a bit different from bash/emacs, and I'd like to change that.

Instead of description of all differences, let me just show you step by step behaviour of bash. I marked cursor as "^" symbol.

```
foo bar --non-needed-param --needed-param^
```

M-b

```
foo bar --non-needed-param --needed-^param
```

M-b

```
foo bar --non-needed-param --^needed-param
```

M-b

```
foo bar --non-needed-^param --needed-param
```

M-b

```
foo bar --non-^needed-param --needed-param
```

M-b

```
foo bar --^non-needed-param --needed-param
```

M-b

```
foo ^bar --non-needed-param --needed-param
```

M-f

```
foo bar^ --non-needed-param --needed-param
```

M-d

```
foo bar^-needed-param --needed-param
```

M-d

```
foo bar^-param --needed-param
```

M-d

```
foo bar^ --needed-param
```

This algorithm is both flexible for moving through words, removing parts of them for me. Also it's in emacs, so I'm used to it. I'd like to see it in zsh too. Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have this in my `.zshrc` for exactly that purpose:

```
# Bash-like navigation
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash
```

Edit: Ah, I remember what was missing in order to get everything working as I wanted to. I also overwrote `forward-word-match` by putting the following content into `$ZDOTDIR/functions/forward-word-match` (assuming your `$ZDOTDIR/functions` directory is in `$fpath`; otherwise put it into one or modify the `$fpath` array as well):

```sh
emulate -L zsh
setopt extendedglob

autoload match-words-by-style

local curcontext=":zle:$WIDGET" word
local -a matched_words
integer count=${NUMERIC:-1}

if (( count < 0 )); then
    (( NUMERIC = -count ))
    zle ${WIDGET/forward/backward}
    return
fi

while (( count-- )); do

    match-words-by-style

    # For some reason forward-word doesn't work like the other word
    # commands; it skips whitespace only after any matched word
    # characters.

    if [[ -n $matched_words[4] ]]; then
        # just skip the whitespace and the following word
  word=$matched_words[4]$matched_words[5]
    else
        # skip the word but not the trailing whitespace
  word=$matched_words[5]
    fi

    if [[ -n $word ]]; then
  (( CURSOR += ${#word} ))
    else
  return 1
    fi
done

return 0
```

Comment: Thanks! But it actually acts different from bash (did I do something wrong?). On this situation: "fo^ooo --bar", if you press "M-f", it should go immediately to the end of foooo, like this: "foooo^ --bar", but I enabled as you showed, it will go to this: "foooo --^bar". It actually looks like this plugin just does export WORDCHARS=''.

Comment: My full zsh configuration works as you want it to -- so I guess I've done something more than I've stated in my answer. My WORDCHARS contains quite some more chars though I cannot fathom where it is actually set: ($WORDCHARS is `*?_-.[]~=/&;!#$%^(){}<>`)

Comment: Alright, remembered what it was that made it work and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hmm. If I do select-word-style bash and then set WORDCHARS -- WORDCHARS doesn't matter. Looks like select-word-style bash has some other configuration parameters.

Comment: This is insane! Can't believe you don't have 25 upvotes. **Works!**

Comment: If I don't set `ZDOTDIR` (then it defaults to $HOME) and I use oh-my-zsh, then how can I apply this solution?

Comment: @Forethinker did you get this working for oh-my-zsh?

Comment: @MoritzBunkus `forward-word-match` overwriting seems doesn't need any more.

Answer (score 5):

To get your desired behavior with Emacs keybindings, all I had to do is:

```
bindkey '\ef' emacs-forward-word
```

This part of Moriz Bunkus' answer seems to work by itself now, too:

```
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash
```

It seems to perform even better in some edge cases (e.g. it treats `?` as a word boundary while the above does not.)