# Deleting word like bash in zsh (autoload is not working)

Tags: zsh

I have the following code in my .zshrc and I have .oh-my-zshell installed.

The following line, however, does not work as it is described in other posts:

```
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash
```

Is there other options I need to add in order to make it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make zsh forward-word behaviour same as in bash/emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847255/how-to-make-zsh-forward-word-behaviour-same-as-in-bash-emacs)

Answer (score 4):

if you want `'^W'` bash behavior you may need to unset `WORDCHARS` or place them in seperate functions and bind you newly created functions.

As i am not using you example, here is my way to accomplish this, second example is also for bash compatibility using `<A-Backspace>` which respect WORDCHAR defined as follow

```
x-bash-backward-kill-word(){
    WORDCHARS='' zle backward-kill-word

}
zle -N x-bash-backward-kill-word
bindkey '^W' x-bash-backward-kill-word

x-backward-kill-word(){
    WORDCHARS='*?_-[]~\!#$%^(){}<>|`@#$%^*()+:?' zle backward-kill-word
}
zle -N x-backward-kill-word 
bindkey '\e^?' x-backward-kill-word
```

Comment: this does not work for me still, with or without `autoload` part I mentioned in my question. Is having oh-my-zsh cause some conflict?

Comment: oh-my-zsh is full of features which can sometimes give headache. I suggest you to try this snippets without oh-my-zsh, and without autoload stuff you mentioned. Then evalute oh-my-zsh and distribute needed stuff in small files and source them through .zshrc.

Comment: Change WORDCHARS='' to WORDCHARS='`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:",<.>/?'"'"

Comment: @Bohr Thank you so much!

Comment: This works for me given this environment:
1. I DO NOT have oh-my-zsh installed
2. On macOS works for DELETION, but not for jumping over words
3. On ubuntu it works both for deletion AND jumping over words