# How do I make ctrl-arrow jumping over words in bash work with special characters?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, input, zsh

I find possibility to jump over words using ctrl-arrow very convenient.
But, for some reason, the special characters after the space make jumping omit the space. For example (`ctrl+left` pressed between arrows and `|` denotes position of the coursor)

`command -flag /home/path| -> command -flag /home/|path -> command -flag /|home/path
-> command -|flag /home/path -> |command -flag /home/path`

This behavior annoys me much - do you know of the way to set it up to make cursor stop at the beginning of each word **including special characters?**

Expected behavior example:

`command -flag /home/path| -> command -flag /home|/path -> command -flag |/home/path
-> command |-flag /home/path -> |command -flag /home/path`

I personally use zsh + linux, but would expect an OS/shell-independent solution to exist.

Comment: Cursor movement is decidedly shell-dependent; it's the shell that handles input at the prompt. `bash` uses the GNU `readline` library; `zsh` uses its own line editor `zle`. Further, your terminal emulator is going to decide what keys are even available; control-arrow needs to be configured at that level to send an appropriate character sequence the shell can interpret.

Comment: Probably - but it behaves in the same way in bash/zsh/chrome/firefox now. I am interested in a solution for zsh.

Comment: @chepner left out one caveat: the *shell* determines what characters comprise a *word*.  It is nice if bash and zsh agree on that from the example given, it sounds as if OP is asking about vi-mode), but one cannot count on this coincidence.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847255/how-to-make-zsh-forward-word-behaviour-same-as-in-bash-emacs.